# bootstrap 3.3.5 carousel, transition between images,images are half height

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-carousel

The error I get from the carousel is the following, When switching images, the next one is on half on the transition, when it ends, it gets the full height. And sometimes, the next image blinks a lot, changing the width and height until the transition is done.

Here is some images:

[1 is the previous image, 2 is the next one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RiTwL.png)
 
[next image height wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10vfa.png)
[next image height wrong 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3cNC.png)

I didn't modified anything, I simply used the carousel from the docs (https://bootstrapdocs.com/v3.3.5/docs/javascript/#carousel) with some minor changes in the html, because I use twig and php `(https://jsfiddle.net/z2rh5o6m/4/)`
and nothing else.

If someone know what is causing this, I appreciate, Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! It's best to keep questions and answers as self-contained and concise as possible. You might want to revise your question with this in mind, e.g. describe the unintended behavior and elaborate on the "minor changes", select the (small) parts of the code that you think are critical.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I tried to make the error more concise! The minor changes in the html is self-explanatory I think, if you take a look at the carousel doc and my code you'll se its the same thing, except for some lines, where i make a  "for loop" because of the dynamically quantity of images.

Comment: Better to check again your code to narrow it down as there are many things that can affect your slider. Check your mark up, css, and javascript and see which one is having problems then make your way from there.